# How to define 2 constructors with 2 different type of HashMaps?

Tags: java, constructor, hashmap, polymorphism

I have a class with 2 HashMap fields as follows-

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map1;
HashMap<String, String> map2;
```

Now, I want to only pass one of the maps in the constructor, that is either of type of map1 or of map2. However, I am not able to define 2 different constructors with HashMaps of different types. Is that a workaround for this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A few options:

1) One constructor that takes both maps and is safe when passed a null.

```
public MyClass( Map<String, Integer> map1, Map<String, String> map2 ) {
    if ( map1 != null ) { this.map1 = map1; }
    if ( map2 != null ) { this.map2 = map2; }
}
```

2) Setters for each map

```
public MyClass {
    private Map<String, Integer> map1;
    private Map<String, String> map2;
    public void setMap1( Map<String, Integer> map1 ) {
        this.map1 = map1;
    }
    public void setMap2( Map<String, String> map2 ) {
        this.map2 = map2;
    }
}
```

3) A builder that allows you to differentiate between the maps and constructs the object properly (calling the setters)

```
public MyClass {
    private Map<String, Integer> map1;
    private Map<String, String>  map2;
    // pretend you don't want people to be able to swap out the map after construction so you protect the setter here.
    protected void setMap1( Map<String, Integer> map1 ) {
        this.map1 = map1;
    }
    protected void setMap1( Map<String, String> map2 ) {
        this.map2 = map2;
    }
    // getters for the maps and other properties
    public static Builder builder() {
        return new Builder();
    }
    public static class Builder {
        private Map<String, Integer> map1;
        private Map<String, String> map2;
        public Builder withMap1( Map<String, Integer> map ) {
            map1 = map;
            return this;
        }
        public Builder withMap2( Map<String, String> map ) {
            map2 = map;
            return this;
        }
        public MyClass build() {
            MyClass c = new MyClass();
            // possibly conditional code that inspects the maps for specific values or validity
            c.setMap1( map1 );
            c.setMap2( map2 );
            // initialization of other fields
            return c;
        }
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        // sample usage
        MyClass instance1 = MyClass.builder().withMap1(myMap1).build();
        MyClass instance2 = MyClass.builder().withMap2(myMap2).build();
        MyClass instance3 = MyClass.builder().withMap1(myMap1).withMap2(myMap2).build();
    }
}
```

4) Static factory (as pointed out by Evgeniy Dorofeev below)

```
public MyClass {
    private Map<String, Integer> map1;
    private Map<String, String> map2;
    // other properties

    private MyClass() {}

    public static MyClass withMap1(Map<String, Integer> map ) {
        MyClass c = new MyClass();
        c.map1 = map;
        return c;
    }
    public static MyClass withMap2(Map<String, String> map ) {
        MyClass c = new MyClass();
        c.map2 = map;
        return c;
    }
    // getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer.  It provides a workaround to the problem.  +1

Comment: I don't understand why you check for `null` in the first solution. AFAIK assigning `null` shouldn't create any error, and at that point in the code `this.mapX` are `null`s which means that assigning `null` wont change a thing. I could understand that if there was an `else` initializing the `mapX` attribute to a new empty hash-map, but as it stands those `if` seem pretty useless. Or am I wrong?

Comment: In this case, yes, the null check is redundant, but I put it in there simply to demonstrate that they can do whatever they want. Perhaps at declaration (which isn't shown in the code sample) they are initializing map1 and map2 to an empty hashmap so they don't have to do null checks elsewhere. Then the null check makes sense in the constructor so as not to override the default value.

Comment: I think you have missed the return type `MyClass` in methods `withMap1` and `withMap2` in example #4.

Comment: The second option doesn't seem to work, the error is `Erasure of method xxx(Map<Long,Long>) is the same as another method in type xxx`

Comment: You are right @ChristosK. The method names needed to be different. I have fixed it in the code sample.

Answer (score 14):

You can't: generics get stripped out during the compilation stage: the compiled code just sees `HashMap<Object, Object>` in both cases.

The technical name for this process is *type erasure*. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

In many ways that makes Java generics inferior to C++ templates.

Comment: Absolutely, Java templates do not support true generic programming. The C++ templates do support the true paradigm of generic programming, which allows you to do extremely powerful things.  I'll leave most of the magic of writing it to the Boost people, I just like to use it. Java templates are syntactic sugar but add no real power.

Comment: *the compiled code just sees `HashMap<Object, Object>` in both cases.* -> No it actually sees `HashMap`.

Answer (score 8):

As a workaround you could use static factory methods with different names

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyObject<T> {
    public MyObject(Map<String, T> map) {
         // process map
    }
}
```

Then you can create your object with:

```
new MyObject<Integer>(map1);
new MyObject<String>(map2);
```

The question is: What do you want to do with a generic map inside MyObject...?

Another solution is:

```
public class MyObject {
    public <T> MyObject(Map<String, T> map) {
        // process map
    }
}
```

This is even more easy to use, because the type argument T is inferred at compile time:

```
new MyObject(map1);
new MyObject(map2);
```

However, you will not be able to determine the concrete type of T at runtime...

Comment: This would only allow the object to contain a single Map. If the OP is using 2 Maps internally only because he doesn't know how to handle generics then this is a great answer. If the OP actually needs to be able to reference 2 Maps during usage of the object (but only wants to specify one at construction) then I don't think this is quite as good a fit.

Comment: I actually require both the Maps and so I am not using generics. Thanks for the answer though

Answer (score 0):

HashMap map1 and HashMap map2 are completely different. They can't be interchangeable. So, you need define a construction passing two hash maps.

```
  public MyClass(HashMap<String, Integer> map1, HashMap<String, String> map2){
        ............
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer provided by [digitaljoel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67598/digitaljoel) ... But there can be few improvements to Builder Pattern provided as 3rd option for your workaround.
One of the major advantages of Builder Pattern is that it eliminates the setter functions from parent class, and the client now calls the setter-like functions of builder class to set instance variables of parent class.

```
public class MyClass{
    private Map<String, Integer> map1;
    private Map<String, String> map2;

    public static Builder builder() {
        return new Builder();
    }

    public static class Builder {
        private Map<String, Integer> map1;
        private Map<String, String> map2;

        public Builder withMap1(Map<String, Integer> map) {
            map1 = map;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withMap2(Map<String, String> map) {
            map2 = map;
            return this;
        }

        public MyClass build() {
            return new MyClass(this);
        }

    }

    public MyClass(Builder b) {
        map1 = b.map1;
        map2 = b.map2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // sample usage
        MyClass instance1 = MyClass.builder().withMap1(myMap1).build();
        MyClass instance2 = MyClass.builder().withMap2(myMap2).build();
        MyClass instance3 = MyClass.builder().withMap1(myMap1).withMap2(myMap2).build();
    }
}
```